# Show preview images of my site content in Google Search Results

Tags: seo, google, youtube

If you search for a video in Google and youtube search results are shown, you see a preview picture in the search results.

I have a video site like youtube and I want my videos also shown with images in google search results. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Are you looking to get your page with a youtube video embedded listed or an existing video that is on youtube listed in the search results? Can you include a little more detail in your post, it'll help people provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is purely up to Google what video site get their videos embedded in Google SERPs.  As of right now, I believe only Youtube videos are embedded directly in Google's SERPs but then Google owns Youtube so that makes sense.

If Google ever does support videos being embedded in their results other than Youtube, they will most likely have to follow the schema.org format (http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html).  Schema.org is a site run by Google, Yahoo, and Microsoft that gives schema templates for people to put into their sites to help their specific types of data to appear more often and more accurately in SERPs for both engines (Yahoo uses Microsoft's, so their are only really 2).

Comment: so you mean there is no way to do that?

Comment: I do not know of a way currently.  With Google and Microsoft holding all of the power in that regard, it is a tough thing.  Your only other option would be to load your videos into Youtube and putting both on the same page. I am not sure if that would work but it is an option.

Comment: Is there any Google groups which would allow me ask about this and get an answer from Google experts?

Comment: You could try asking a question on http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/. You may get a response.